# How can I renable my wifi controller after modprobe -rv?

Tags: wireless, modprobe

I was trying to improve the wifi signal range, but when I executed the command `sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be`my wifi stopped working and I cannot do anything.

How I do reset the config or rollback this changes?

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and then do `cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999` and edit the question to add the URL.  You have a messed up conf file somewhere

Comment: In `terminal`, what does `modinfo rtl8723be` show?

Comment: @Jeremy31 why do you think so? My wifi stops working when I pull the driver out of the kernel too!

Comment: @Zanna a reply about a modprobe rtl8723be in an answer I deleted was that the result was `fatal, you can not insert rtl8723be`

Comment: @Jeremy31 oh I see! That's not the real error message though, so maybe they just mistyped it. If it really doesn't work, the question is unclear, because everything implies the WiFi worked fine before running the command and that the command worked as expected

Comment: @Zanna I suspect a conf file change before the modprobe -rv

Answer (score 3):

The command `sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be` removed the module from the running kernel (that's what the `-r` option does - it's short for `--remove`).

This doesn't alter any configuration, so the driver will be inserted again on the next boot. To insert it manually, run `sudo modprobe rtl8723be` (without the `-r` option). You don't need the `-v` option; it only makes the command's output more verbose. Also see [man modprobe](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/modprobe.8.html) for more information.